# Java generic method for primitives

Tags: java, generics, methods, primitive

I have a very creative solution to allow my unsigned code all access through my signed library. Although bad practice, I fear I have no other solution (except rewriting a lot of code, that then needs to be rewrited back).

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class full {
    public static <T,S,P> S access(final T object, final String function, final P parameter) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<S>() {
            @Override
            public S run() {
                try {
                    if (parameter == null) {
                        Class[] argTypes = { };
                        Object passedArgv[] = { };
                        return (S)object.getClass().getMethod(function, argTypes).invoke(object, passedArgv);
                    } else {
                        Class[] argTypes = { parameter.getClass() };
                        Object passedArgv[] = { parameter };
                        return (S)object.getClass().getMethod(function, argTypes).invoke(object, passedArgv);
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works great for functions that return Objects, but not for primitives.
Boolean bool = full.access(..);
will result in a nullpointer, because generic methods can't handle primitives.

Any ideas about how to take the right approach?

To test:

```
public static Boolean test() {
    return true;
}

public Main() {
    System.out.println(((Boolean)redirect.full.access(this, "test", null)));
}
```

Comment: The `Boolean` type is not a primitive (which is why it can be null) but rather a wrapper class around a `bool`. The `bool` type is a primitive -- thus, the NPE lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a `NullPointerException` is because you are always returning `null`.  You call `doPrivileged(...)`, yet `null` is still returned.  Try returning the output of `doPrivileged(...)`.  By the looks of things, Auto(un)boxing is working here on both the inputs and the returned outputs.

This worked for me (I passed in a primitive int, and expected a primitive boolean):

```
public class ATest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        int i = 5;
        Object equals = new Object();

        boolean b = full.access(i, "equals", equals);

        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static class full
    {
        public static <T, S, P> S access(final T object, final String function, final P parameter)
        {
            return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<S>()
            {
                @Override
                public S run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (parameter == null)
                        {
                            Class[] argTypes = {};
                            Object passedArgv[] = {};
                            return (S) object.getClass().getMethod(function, argTypes)
                                    .invoke(object, passedArgv);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Class[] argTypes = { parameter.getClass() };
                            Object passedArgv[] = { parameter };
                            return (S) object.getClass().getMethod(function, argTypes)
                                    .invoke(object, passedArgv);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchMethodException ex)
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
                    }
                    catch (SecurityException ex)
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
                    }
                    catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
                    }
                    catch (InvocationTargetException ex)
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(full.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

On another note, you could make this more robust.  When I passed in an `Integer` instead of an `Object`, the equals method was not found, even though it would have been a valid method call.  If you do not find the method with the given `Class`, you should check again with the classes' parent classes.

Comment: Thanks! Totally overlooked that! *facepalm*

Comment: I have not tried yet, but I think it should work just fine. I think it has more trouble with void functions.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what the primitive classes are for? ( Boolean, Integer... ) I'm not sure if they'll do it, I haven't checked.

Long answer : make a clone of all those methods to return primitives.

Or much shorter; you could just wrap the primitive type you want in an object, that is do something like:

```
public class MyInt {
    public int intValue;
}
```

Comment: That is one way to go. However it requires passing a Class as argument, so I can see what type the returnvalue is and then wrap it appropriatly. I am going to try this if no other options are avaiable.